# Is an eager-graph compatible same code solution possible?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to write code that is eager and graph compatible. However, there is very little information online for how to do this, being a literal footnote on TensorFlow's [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#write_compatible_code). Furthermore, what they have wrote is confusing, saying:

> The same code written for eager execution will also build a graph during graph execution. Do this by simply running the same code in a new Python session where eager execution is not enabled.

This implies that a same code solution is possible, where the only change required is the addition or removal of `tf.enable_eager_execution()`.

Currently I use `tf.keras` to define my model and `tf.data` for my input pipeline. However, many eager operations don't work in graph, with the opposite also being true.

For example, I keep track of my number of `epochs` using `tf.train.Checkpoint()`. In eager mode, after restoring I can access it using `epochs.numpy()` to assign its value to a local variable. However, this does not work with graphs, which instead would require `sess.run(epochs)` due to the values not being defined during execution.

Again, to compute my gradients in eager I need to use some form of autograd, in my case `tf.GradientTape()`. This is not compatible with graphs, as "tf.GradientTape.gradients() does not support graph control flow."

I see that `tfe.py_func` exists, but once again, this only works when eager is not enabled, thus not helping for this problem.

So how do I make a same code solution, when it seems that many aspects of eager and graph directly conflict with each other?