# How do I export an eager execution model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Having completed my model, I now wish to export and deploy it, following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic#train_and_export_tensorflow_model) tutorial on TensorFlow's website. However, there is no indication of how to do this in eager execution, where I am unable to provide a session or graph to `builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables()`.

Is this a case where my code needs to be eager and graph compatible, or where I need to save my model, import it to a session, and export it from there?

Comment: See [Work with graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#work_with_graphs) in the Eager Execution guide. As it says there, "deploying code written for eager execution is more difficult", and you will need to do some extra work for yourself. That said, [eager mode will become even more relevant in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52994183/1782792), and we may see improvements in that area.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jdehesa! I am looking forward to 2.0, but it probably isn't releasing till December. Between "either generate a graph from the model, or run the Python runtime and code directly on the server," I guess I will try for the former. This seems like its the same problem I have raised with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213653/is-an-eager-graph-compatible-same-code-solution-possible), as many methods only work for either graph or eager, not both.